# Reading and significance of dakuten with kana for which it normally is not used

Tags: hiragana

[image: weird hiragana?]
[image: weird hiragana?]

Came across these while reading a novel.

How do you read this?

Comment: I'm not sure about the あ, but the latter is definitely ゔ, pronounced 'vu' for imported words. It usually is in katakana though. [Here](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E3%82%94#Japanese) is a little bit more information.

Comment: Outside of ゔ (which is /vu/), they seem to be associated with screaming and yelling and such things. but I'm not sure enough of the specifics.

Comment: Can you give more context?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The letter あ゛doesn't exist indeed in Japanese. But あ゛is rarely used in manga to emphasize the letter あ. 
The letter ゔ exists. But it is normally written in katakana.

Pronunciation:
ゔぁ => va
ゔぃ => vi
ゔ => v or vu
ゔぇ => ve
ゔぉ => vo

Comment: The "v" sound does not even exist in our language.  How do you expect us to produce it?

Comment: Because that's technically how it's supposed to be pronounced. Whether people do pronounce it like that or not is a different story.

Comment: Actually, we don't use う゛ for the purpose of representing "vu" any longer.