# Speech impediment - slurred speech

Tags: spoken-language, terminology

Is there a name for a speech impediment like this where, for lack of a better description, it sounds like you're talking after you've bitten your tongue?

#### 「いだだきまあず」　→　いただきます

[image]

#### 「ごぢぞうざまでぢだあ」　→　ごちそうさまでした

[image]

[Here's the video](https://youtu.be/-ktqEPdOz1s?t=6m23s) I took the screenshots from, but the audio doesn't completely match the words on the screen.  (Also, I couldn't figure out how to link between a particular start and end time on the video.)

Comment: Could you add an audio clip? There are several possibilities such as how hearing impaired people or how stroke victims speak. Or just quick, informal native speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a word [鼻声【はなごえ】](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/178286/meaning/m0u/), which is understood by all native speakers. Exaggerated examples would be:

> - がぜびぎまじだぁ （風邪引きましたぁ）
> - [あ゛あ゛あ゛](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32622/5010)、ごめんなざい～ （ごめんなさい～）

But this usually refers to a temporary symptom of a normal human being.

For a yokai like this, I would use 鼻の詰まったような声, 鼻にかかったような声, [くぐもった](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/60868/meaning/m0u/)声, [こもった](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/82367/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%93%E3%82%82%E3%82%8B/)声 or 濁った声. You can use 常に濁音で喋る although this doesn't look technical at all.