# Dakuten on る character

Tags: pronunciation, hiragana

I saw a dakuten used on a る, but it doesn't seem to exist in basic rules. My assumption is it's some sort of slang or implied definition as opposed to "proper" Japanese (it was in a manga). Does anyone know the meaning?

Comment: It could be [this](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32622/5010), but you saw dakuten only with る? Wasn't that dakuten characters in a row, like [this one](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%82%86%E3%82%99%E3%82%8B%E3%82%99%E3%81%96%E3%82%93%E3%82%99!!)?

Answer (score 14):

Japanese is a highly "playable" language both in spoken and written forms.

「る゛」 would just ”mean” the same thing as the regular 「る」 but with some kind of **emphasis, exclamation, emotionality**, etc. intended by the author added.  As a manga reader, you can pronounce 「る゛」 as 「る」 because there is no "official pronunciation" for 「る゛」.

This can be said about any kana with 「゛」 found in manga, excluding the ones that actually exist in regular writing.

Here, the hero shouts 「ゆ゛る゛さ゛ん゛！！」 and that is 「許{ゆる}さん！！」 ("Unacceptable!!") said emphatically.

[image]

Just found this; Talk about emotionality.  "I've got friends!!!!"

[image]

Comment: While the pronunciation doesn't change, the sound does. The dakuten indicate vibration of the vocal cords (か unvoiced, が same sound voiced; true for all standard and dakuten pairs). This usage in manga is related to that concept. In the 仮面ライダー example, it's being said with a growl. In the One Piece example, it's being said with such force that the voice "breaks" getting that "r" rolled in the throat effect (sorry don't know how else to describe it). How the sound changes comes from context. If you know what I mean and add it to your answer I think it would be very complete for future readers.

Comment: I immediately think of a robotic voice, like the Great Fox (R.O.B.?) in the Star Fox series.