# Why is there dakuten on the "ん" in this image? (ん゙)

Tags: kana

Context: http://mangalifewin.takeshobo.co.jp/rensai/yo-jolife/yo-jo-008/21231/

Does "ん" really have a dakuten version?

[image]

Comment: related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32627/22352

Comment: also related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/44935/5010

Answer (score 6):

**My Research:**

So my reasearch has been a little bit unusual for this one, but I found the following from reddit's [r/learnjapanese](https://www.reddit.com/r/LearnJapanese/comments/70pisv/katakana_irregular_voiced_consonants_manga/dn4ygxm/):

> Dakuten/handakuten on kana where they would normally not be found can imply a muffled, nasal, or slurred sound.

I also found some sources on this stack exchange as well.  [Their question](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32622/22352) was about dakuten being applied to あ.

As @naruto notes:

> あ゛ used to be commonly used in manga to express an exclamation — "aagh!" or something like that. I feel it has become less common (if not rare) these days. え゛、い゛、お゛、の゛ and so on are sometimes used in a similar way. You may see them in casual blogs and tweets, but never in formal documents.

On [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E6%BF%81%E7%82%B9), I found that ん゙ can signify a guttural "hmmm?"

Finaly, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dakuten_and_handakuten), I found the following:

> In informal writing, dakuten is occasionally used on vowels to indicate a shocked or strangled articulation; for example, on あ゙ or ゔ. Dakuten can also be occasionally used with ん (ん゙) to indicate a guttural hum, growl, or similar sound.

---

**My conclusion:**

I believe that you're looking at something that is informal.  For the most part, it looks like someone is saying "hmmm?" in a guttural, excited, or muffled matter, depending on the context.