# Dakuon on kanji and hiragana where it's not normally used

Tags: kanji, hiragana

https://twitter.com/motokazu95/status/1469469575930871808

> 小林さんと**酒゛**が゛**飲゛み゛**た゛**い゛**！

In this tweet dakuon is used after a kanji and on these hiragana where I've never seen them used before, which I've marked in bold. Is this a stylistic way of representing drunk slurred speech in Japanese, or does this signify something else?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/44938/30454

Comment: It's not a slurred speech but the opposite of it. If anything, this would be pronounced strongly and emphatically.