# What’s written?

Tags: manga, kana, writing-identification

[image]

How do i read this ? I didn’t find the letters

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/44938/1478 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/32622/1478 https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/23732/1478

Comment: @snailboat you guys might wanna compile a list-question with all the common "sound effects" like that to link these new questions to

Comment: ん like you would normally pronounce ん, but while imitating a car engine revving. Like if a person accidentally bumped his head and he wants to yell/curse in pain, but he realizes he's in a very quiet library.